# "variableB = $+variableA""

Tags: powershell, variables, variable-assignment

**Script:**

```
$ZZSG1 = "SGvcenter.domain.com"
$ZZBLR2 = "BlgvCenter.domain.com"
$ZZUS2 = "USvCenter.domain.com"
$siteid = Read-Host "enter physical site id eg:ZZUS2" 
$siteids = "ZZSG1","ZZBLR2","ZZUS2"
if ($siteids -notcontains $siteid) {
Write-Host "siteid not found"}
else{
$SID = "$"+"$siteid"
Write-Host "$siteid contains this vCenter $SID"}
$SID
```

**Output:**

> ZZSG1 contains this vCenter $ZZSG1
>
> $ZZSG1

**Expected Output:**

> ZZSG1 contains this vCenter SGvcenter.domain.com
>
> SGvcenter.domain.com

Comment: Please edit your question to explicitly state a question as well as the script language.

Comment: It appears this is a power shell script, given [write-host](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177031.aspx) and [-notcontains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Comparison_Operators).

Comment: @SamOnela Yes, but it's good practice to the OP to state it.

Comment: I am new to this group. Sure. I will add the required details to my future posts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of $SID is going to be set a string of the name variable not the value of the variable. Try something like this to get the variable value.

Replace:

```
$SID = "$"+"$siteid"
```

with:

```
$SID = (Get-Variable $siteid).value
```